# How do I refactor this new component?

Tags: reactjs

I'm taking [this course](https://fullstackopen.com/en/part1/introduction_to_react#exercises)  and working through the exercises (exercise in question is the last one toward the bottom) but I don't know of a course specific community to ask questions.

Anyway,

I'm asked to refactor the following code:

```
  return (
    <div>
      <p>
        {props.part1} {props.exercises1}
      </p>
      <p>
        {props.part2} {props.exercises2}
      </p>
      <p>
        {props.part3} {props.exercises3}
      </p>

    </div>
  )
}
```

so that I only render three "Part" components which then renders the name and number of exercises.

Like this:

```
  return (
    <div>
      <Part .../>
      <Part .../>
      <Part .../>
    </div>
  )
}
```

But with some sort of props function in each ''

The usual error is that I'm using an undefined variable whether is is a "Part" variable or specifically part1, part2, part3 which are all defined when I use the un-factored code.

I was able to successfully refactor a different component but this one I'm getting stuck on.

Comment: You have to show what you have tried

Comment: I've tried variations of  


<Part {props.part1} /> 
 

or just 

<Part {part1} />  

Or   

<Part part={part1} />

But each time I run into the undefined variable error but that's how I was able to successfully refactor my Header component where I could say:      
   
<Header course={course} />

Comment: Have you tried <Part part={props.part1} />? It seems this should be the answer, based on the info you gave so far.

Comment: `<Part part={props.part1}  exercise={props.exercises1}/> ` but you should consider changing the outer props to be arrays so you can more easily iterate over them

Comment: I'll try this. The very next exercise has me turn it into an array but I want to make sure I can make this work before I move on. Thanks!